# Use of operator ()

Tags: c++, operators

I have few question about `()` operator. Please help me  to get clear idea.

1. What is the use of `()` operator (`()` operator overloading).
2. In which situations it should use.
3. What are the  practical example of `()` operator usage (in which situations that useful,convenient or suitable to use `()` operator ).

Comment: Used in functors, function objects that can be passed to library algorithms

Comment: Arrrr, piratical examples?

Comment: Any functional object defined in the C++ Standard defines this operator. for example std::cout << std::plus<int>()( 10, 20 ) << std::endl; They are used usually in standard and others algorithms.

Comment: I once used this in conjunction with overloading the [] operator. The [] operator returned a writable reference, the () returned a read-only reference. I don't know if it's suitable, but it sure was convenient and the code was still pretty readable.

Answer (score 5):

It's primarily used in function objects to simulate function calls.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Functor
{
   void operator()() {
      std::cout << "lol\n";
   }
};

int main()
{
   Functor f;
   f();  // output: "lol"
}
```

#### [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c32dd258942d7f7c)

A contrived example, yes, but this gets more complex with constructor arguments and when, say, storing this functor for use in an algorithm. It's very common in the C++ standard library.

---

You don't *have* to use it in this way; another example is simulating multi-dimensional array access:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct Matrix
{
   Matrix(unsigned m, unsigned n)
      : m(m), n(n), vs(m*n) {}

   T& operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j)
   {
      return vs[i + m * j];
   }

private:
   unsigned m;
   unsigned n;
   std::vector<T> vs;

};

/**    
 *       _~
 *    _~ )_)_~
 *    )_))_))_)
 *    _!__!__!_
 *    \______t/
 *  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 */
int main()
{
   const unsigned int WIDTH = 3;
   const unsigned int HEIGHT = 3;

   Matrix<long> m(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
   m(1,1) = 42;
}
```

This one is useful because `operator[]` may take only one parameter (though that parameter can be an initializer list, which is a workaround).

Comment: Where are the pirates? :( *alt: -1 No pirates.*

Comment: @dyp: I pirated the `Matrix` code from Freenode `##C++`'s help bot :)

Comment: +1:  Great answer.  Theres really not much more that can be said.

Answer (score 1):

The () operator is used to make what is known as a function object aka "functor"

There are some very interesting things that having a function object allows one to do including passing a function object as a parameter.

The link I am posting below is a video from a class I was taking where the professor is talking about functors. I find it very helpful. (Note: the vid also talks about class templates)

[Functors and Templates](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BQz0ZXMye4)

Comment: `passing a function call as a parameter`?

Comment: Can you not pass a functor as a parameter?

Comment: Yes but that's not what you said!